# translating curl params to httr POST

Tags: r, analytics, httr

I'd like to translate this (working from CLI) cURL call to [httr::POST()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.0/topics/POST) so that will be easier to reuse:

```
curl --data 'api_key=abc123' --data-urlencode 'event=[{"user_id":"u1", "event_type":"e_0224"}]' https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi
```

This is my latest attempt using httr::POST()

```
params <- list()
params$api_key <- "abc123"
event <- list()
event$user_id <- "u1"
event$event_type <- "e_0224"
params$event <- event

r <- POST(url = "https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi", 
          body = params,
          encode = "json")
```

I get this error:

```
 httr::text_content(r)
 [1] "missing_event"
```

Comment: can you add some of the errors? They may give a clue.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more details and the latest error.

Comment: difficult one to diagnose. I've had similar experiences with `httr` when using the facebook api. My recommendation is to `paste` together `event=[{"user_id":"u1", "event_type":"e_0224"}]` and pass through as a string.

Comment: Thanks, this worked: `params$event <- '[{"user_id":"u1", "event_type":"e_0224"}]'` . I can use paste for the parameters.

Comment: cool - the square and curly braces cause problems in `httr`; there's probably a way around it, but I couldn't find it documented so ended up with the method above.